# Feed multiple Inputs into Graph using data.dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to feed data to CTC LSTM network using tensorflow am using the Dataset API to feed data to placeholders. For that I have created a

iterator.get_next() iter_val whose output is

```
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:0' shape=(?, ?, 16) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:1' shape=(?, ?) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:2' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:3' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>)
```

My placeholders are

```
train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, num_features])
target_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,1])
out_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,1])

loss = Result of operations of the above placeholders
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

when I try to run the session as

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(num_epochs):
      sess.run(iter_val)
      _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss))
      print(loss_value)
```

I get the error

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder_11' with dtype int32 and shape [?,1]      [[node
>   Placeholder_11 (defined at :30) ]]

I am clearly not feeding this session properly so how do I feed the session properly

Comment: Could you provide more information, which one is the placeholder named 'Placeholder_11'?. But in general, you can specify the operation(train) and feed values needed using 'feed_dict = {place_holder : value}' .

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code where you are linking the elements from the dataset api to the placeholders?

Comment: @gorjan thanks for the help but I in the end decided to work with eager execution.